# Absolute path in a web app

Tags: javascript, html, web, web-applications, tomcat8.5

This may sound like a dumb question.

I received a (basic) web application developed by another person, using *HTML* and *JavaScript*. In this application he used his *JavaScript* file path as `/javascripts/_FileName_.js`. But when I tried to run it on a *Tomcat (8.5)* server, those JavaScript files didn't executed. But when I changed the path to `javascripts/_FileName_.js` (Without the `/` at the beginning), it worked fine.

This application was already ran in a server and it worked fine. What has to be the problem here ?

Comment: Removing the leading slash tells Tomcat to start looking for that file at the root of the application context.

Comment: @duffymo So what's the difference it makes with the leading slash ?

Comment: The leading slash means "Tomcat root".  Not the same as the application context root.

Comment: @duffymo Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as **@duffymo** described in comments, the *leading slash* tells tomcat to start looking for that file at the root of the application context, which is the `webapps` folder in tomcat. But if we remove that *leading slash*, it searches for the file from the current folder.

That was the problem. I am posting this as an answer because he mentioned these in comments only.